# Call Csharp from Javascript in xamarin unhandled exception

Tags: javascript, xamarin, webview, xamarin.android

I tried to call csharp method from javascript in webview according to xamarin documentation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/webview/call_csharp_from_javascript/).

```
public class CallcSharpFromJs : Java.Lang.Object
{

    [Export]
    [JavascriptInterface]
    public void OpenLightGalleryPopUp()
    {
        CallMehtodFromJs.CallLightGalleryPopUp(); 
    }
}
```

When I just put an simple alert to csharp method everything works great. But when I try to change MainPage of my app I get Unhandled Exception.

```
public class CallMehtodFromJs
{
    public static void CallLightGalleryPopUp()
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("alert", "method runs successfully", "ok");
      //  Application.Current.MainPage = new GalleryPage();
    }
}
```

I think it is so weird!
Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you working on Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.Forms? Sorry, what is working and what is not? Your first block calls the code in the second snippet. I could't understand the problem. Could you please add more details? And your html/js?

Comment: I changed my code and now I'm using a hybrid WebView in Xamarin.Forms exactly according the documentation here.
      https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview/
It is working good, but when I just change the method that is called in that documention I mean this 
     DisplayAlert ("Alert", "Hello " + data, "OK")
to another for example Navigation.PushAsync(new GalleryPage());
I got unhandled Exception.
It is so weird.

Comment: OK, you're using X.F, and then? Post your html/js and your code please.

Comment: Any Suggestion?